Misunderstanding kubernetes services
I've been trying to use kubernetes for a while now and i stumbled on a problem that i can't figure out.
I am trying to deploy a react frontend and a rust backend application (as a case of communication between two containers/pods) and everything works fine, they both seem to be working and the frontend can be accessed using minikube service <name-of-service>, the problem is that the frontend tries to fetch data from the backend and it fails with multiple errors:

Websocket connection to 'ws://<minikube-ip>/ws' failed
GET 'http://backend:8080/test' net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED (maybe that's the issue?)
Failed to fetch

I've been trying to change the .yaml files i use to create a deployment and service, and looked at a bunch of ways other people tried doing the same thing, but nothing seemed to help, as they only revealed the specifications of their .yaml files
This is how my frontend deployment and service .yaml file looks like:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: client-deployment
  labels:
    app: client
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: client
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: client
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: client
        image: quan1um/react-test:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: client
    tier: frontend
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
  type: LoadBalancer

backend:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: backend
          image: quan1um/rust-actix-test:latest
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: http
  type: ClusterIP

As you could see from my error messages, my frontend tries to fetch data from http://backend:8080, and i do realize that this is not gonna work since this fetch requests happens on the browser, and the browser has no idea of services on kubernetes and their names.
Even though i only use react for the frontend, i've seen nginx configuration files that used the names specified in .yaml service files for the server configutation block and im curious about that too

If you want to call anything from outside K8s (i.e. the browser) you need to expose and ingress.
With minikube it's a little more complicated. Look at this example.
You'll need something like this:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-example
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /backend
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: backend
            port:
              number: 8080

